# How are specific linear maps defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm revising for exams and a question that often crops up is: given a linear map $\mathcal{T}:\;\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, describe how to represent $\mathcal{T}$ as a matrix relative to bases $\mathfrak{B}_n,\mathfrak{B}_m$ of $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m$.

What confuses me is how $\mathcal{T}$ can be defined in the first place without referring to bases. Is it implied that $\mathcal{T}$ is defined under the standard bases? Or at least under *some* bases? (if so then I know how to answer the question)

Comment: You could define a linear map by $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $T(x)=2x$.  This does not refer to a basis.

Comment: @Seth This is exactly the kind of thing that raised my concern; how should I interpret the question then?

Comment: So then you need to fix a basis of your domain and a basis of your codomain and compute the matrix by looking at the coordinates of the image of each basis element in the domain.  This is one of the most important things you learn in linear algebra.

Comment: @Seth Okay, so let $\mathfrak{B}_n=\{\mathbf{v}_1\cdots \mathbf{v}_n\}$ and then find a matrix such that $\mathbf{Mv}_i=\mathcal{T}(\mathbf{v}_i)$ for each $i,$ where $\mathcal{T}(\mathbf{v}_i)$ is expressed with respect to $\mathfrak{B}_m?$

Comment: Not quite.  You want to associate the standard basis $e_i$ to $v_i$.  You want a matrix $M$ such that $Me_i$ has the $\mathfrak{B}_m$ coordinates of $T(v_i)$.  This is surely in your book or notes if you are stuck.  The point is that $M$ takes the $\mathfrak{B}_n$ coordinates of $x$ to the $\mathfrak{B}_m$ coordinates of $T(x)$.

Comment: @Seth Ok, could I make it a bit more longwinded: take the standard basis, see where $T$ sends each element (images in standard basis as well). Write a matrix representing the transformation with respect to the standard bases. Pre/post multiply by change-of-basis matrices to get the desired matrix. Does that work? (thank you for your patience)

Comment: @anaconda Yes, that sounds rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to distinguish between *vectors* and their *representations*, as well as between *linear maps* and their *representations* if you only look at the vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$, because they *look* the same there.

But the idea becomes clear if you pick a vector space where the actual vectors aren't $n$-tuples, but instead something else. A good example is the vector $P_n$ space of real-valued polynomial functions of degree at most $n$. This vector space contains polynomial functions of the form $$
  x \mapsto a_n x^n + \ldots a_1 x + a_0 \text{ for arbitrary } a_1,\ldots,a_0 \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Multiplication of vectors with scalars and sums of vectors are defined *point-wise*, i.e. $$
  (p + q) = x \mapsto p(x) + q(x) \text{, } \lambda p = x \mapsto \lambda p(x) \text{.}
$$
Since every polynomial function of degree at most $n$ can be written at a sum of the $n+1$ *monomial* functions $x \mapsto$, $x \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto x^2$, ... , $x \to x^n$, the vector space obviously has dimension $n+1$.

It's easy to define a linear map on this vector space without *any* references to a matrix. Let $D$ be the (linear!) map that maps a polynomial function to it's derivative, i.e. $$
  D \,:\, P_n \to P_n \,:\, p \mapsto p'
$$

You can similarly define linear functionals, i.e. linear maps from $P_n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ without references to a basis. For *any* real number $\mathbb{c}$, you can define the map $$
  e_c := P_n \to \mathbb{R} \,:\, p \mapsto p(c)
$$

A good exercise for you would be to

1. Show that $P_n$ is indeed a vector space
2. Show that $D$ is a linear map $P_n \to P_n$. Is that map injective? surjective? Find $\ker D$ and $\textrm{img } D$.
3. Find a basis of $P_n$. (The text above actually already states one)
4. Find a matrix representation of $D$ in that basis

If you have already covered dual spaces, you could additionally

1. Find the dual space $P_n'$. Find a basis in terms of suitable chosen $e_c$.
2. Find the dual basis of the basis of $P_n$ you found earlier.
3. Find a matrix representation of $D'$, the dual of $D$, in that basis

Comment: Wow, I had no idea vector spaces could look like this!

Comment: @anaconda, perhaps your course has not taught you about any vector spaces other than ${\Bbb R}^n$, and has thereby given you a rather distorted view of vector spaces.  My institution proposed to do that a few years ago, and I strongly opposed it for exactly this reason.  Indeed, if the course only looks at one kind of vector space, they are missing the whole point of linear algebra, and they might as well study ${\Bbb R}^n$ without mentioning vector spaces.

Comment: @David A thousand times yes! The linear algebra class I took focused *way* to much on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and as I result I was horribly confused. Dual spaces in particular just don't make any sense that way, IMHO. At some point I had had it, and invented some notation that allowed me to distinguish between $n$-tuples that are *coordinates*, and the "raw" elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. And behond! Slowly the confusion started to clear up...

Comment: @anaconda In fact, these are the more *interesting* vector spaces. BTW, note that if you drop requirement that the degree of the polynomials is at most some $n$, you *still* get a vector space! It just doesn't have finite dimension anymore. It still contains only polynomials, though - each *single* element still has some well-defined degree! But there's no global limit on the degree anymore. And note how the differential operator $D$ is *still* a perfectly well-defined linear map.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a really helpful insight! About my original question: would what I described in the last comment on the OP be correct?

Answer (score 1):

This might seem off-topic at first, but if you read on it will be relevant. . . I hope ;-)

Let's start with a true-or-false question: with respect to the standard basis, any vector is the same as its coordinate vector.  For example,
$$\hbox{the coordinate vector of}\quad\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}\quad\hbox{is}\quad
  \pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}\ .$$
True or false?  I would say the statement is *false*.  Sure, the numbers involved are the same, but I would not regard the vectors as being *really* the same, because they are conceptually different.  You can think of the actual vector as a physical object; for example, you can conceptualise it as an arrow.  However, the coordinate vector should not be thought of as a physical object: you should rather think of it as a recipe, or a set of instructions, which says "take $2$ times the first basis vector plus $3$ times the second".

So, a definition like $T({\bf v})=A{\bf v}$ need not be taken to refer to any particular basis at all: you can regard it as saying, "take the physical vector $\bf v$ and perform on it the operations indicated by $A$".  To take a specific example, $A$ might be a rotation matrix: then what we have to do to any vector is to rotate it through a certain angle about the axis specified by another vector, and this can be done without needing to call on any particular basis.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well , the linear map $\mathcal{T}:\;\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a function for which the following two conditions are satisied:

**(1)** $\mathcal{T}(x+y) = \mathcal{T}(x) + \mathcal{T}(y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

**(2)** $ \mathcal{T}(\alpha x)= \alpha \mathcal{T}(x)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

We can represent this linear map by a $m\times n$ matrix. We can represent, say, an element $v$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ using a column matrix of size $n$. When we multiply $v$ by an $m \times n$ matrix, the output is a column matrix of size $m$, which can be identified with some element of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Our task is to find such a matrix $A$, which has the same effect on the elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (identified as column matrices), as does the linear map $\mathcal{T}$. As to how to go about constructing such a matrix, there are several sources availaible online, like the khan academy, MIT opencourse, etc.